# How to roll back to Google Chrome 55

Tags: google-chrome

How to roll back to Google Chrome 55, Now I dont want the solutions, where we download offline exe files or we get a folder which is older version. I want full Chrome 55. By which when I call chrome browser via selenium drivers, It will pick up chrome 55 only. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Chrome browser update (v55) breaks Shoutcast v1.x HTML5 players

Comment: https://www.internet-radio.com/community/threads/latest-chrome-browser-update-v55-breaks-shoutcast-v1-x-html5-players.27560/

Answer (score 0):

Filehippo has plenty of older versions of chrome:
http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history/2/

If you are driving the browser using the chromedriver itself, they can be found here:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html